# Present unicode url on http response django

Tags: xml, django, url, unicode, httpresponse

I want to return httpresponse using django, so I'm using

`return HttpResponse(xml_ans, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')`.

In the response there is a url which is unicode, it looks like this:

`<clickurl>http://something.com?something_id=21&a</clickurl>`

so as you can see the url has the special character &, I'm using 
`urllib2.quote(click_url.encode("utf8"))`
and get

`<clickurl>http%3A//something.com%3Fsomething_id%3D21%26a</clickurl>`

but then I would like to get into the clickurl from the address bar, and I can't.

How do I overcome this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting into XML content, so you need to XML-encode, not URL-encode. The `&` character should come out as `&amp;`. For example.

```
>>> def xml_escape(s):
>>>     return s.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&apos;')

>>> '<clickurl>' + xml_escape('http://www.example.com/?a=b&c=d') + '</clickurl>'
'<clickurl>http://www.example.com/?a=b&amp;c=d</clickurl>'
```

It is usually better to create XML using dedicated tools that can work out the escaping automatically than to try to create XML yourself. For example:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
>>> element = ElementTree.Element('clickurl')
>>> element.text = 'http://www.example.com/?a=b&c=d'
>>> ElementTree.tostring(element)
'<clickurl>http://www.example.com/?a=b&amp;c=d</clickurl>'
```